# How related are the notions of TV and Social Networks "addictions" to lack of physical social interactions?

Tags: addiction, social-networks, enrichment

**QUESTION**

What are (if any) the scientific bases to claim that the people from the western civilization who complained about fictions (e.g. movies, tv series, etc.) and social networks (e.g. Facebook, Instagram, TikTok, etc.) "addictions" are actually lacking "real" (i.e. physical) social interactions in their life, and are resorting to the simulated social interactions to fill voids in their life and, in turn, fail to take efforts to fill them with real social interactions, rendering them dependent to such simulations?

**BACKGROUND**

1. There are various references to the concept of "social media addiction":

   - There are some literary examples (e.g. Flaubert's depiction of "[Madame Bovary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madame_Bovary)") describing people lacking in such personal relations in their life as "escaping" by reading stories full of personal relations.
   - The main character of Cory Doctorow's latest novel "[The Lost Cause](https://craphound.com/category/lostcause/)" has a self-conscious routine before checking social media on his phone to (tentatively) avoid getting addicted to it.
   - Popular health websites title present discussions of "[Social Media Addiction](https://www.healthline.com/health/social-media-addiction)", defined informally as "losing several minutes (or even hours) at a time after using social media", describing the dopamine effect of social media on the human brain.
2. There are some references to addiction behaviors (not just to social media) being related to a lack of social connection:

   - [Johann Hari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johann_Hari) (a [criticized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johann_Hari#2011_plagiarism,_fabrication_and_misconduct_scandal) journalist) claimed in his [TED talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PY9DcIMGxMs) that "[the opposite of addiction is not sobriety, it’s connection](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/love-and-sex-in-the-digital-age/201509/the-opposite-addiction-is-connection)", describing an experiment comparing the potential for addiction between rats in a boring environment  and rats in a life enriched environment.
   - [Robert Weiss](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/love-and-sex-in-the-digital-age/201509/the-opposite-addiction-is-connection) (a Doctor) stated in "Psychology Today" that "many 21st Century addiction specialists have espoused for years (the concept) that addiction is not about the pleasurable effects of substances, it’s about the user’s inability to connect in healthy ways with other human beings. In other words, addiction is not a substance disorder, it’s a social disorder."
   - [Researchers](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-020-67966-8) described (in 2020)  how the recovery from cocaine addiction of rats was greatly improved through environmental enrichment.

So, I am a bit confounded between any addiction being related to social isolation, or addiction to social media being related to it, or no relation between the three phenomenon.

Comment: This seems very broad.